# Finding a special child node using its atrribute with findnodes

Tags: xml, perl, find, xml-libxml

I have an XML file, say:

```
<root_node + attribute>
   <child_node1 + attribute>
      <node1_2 + attribute>
         <node1_3>
            <node1_4 + attribute>
               TEXT COME HERE
            </node1_4> 
         </node1_3> 
      </node1_2> 
   </child_node1>
   <child_node2 + attribute>
      <node2_2 + attribute>
         <node2_3>
            <node2_4 + attribute>
               TEXT COME HERE
            </node2_4> 
         </node2_3> 
      </node2_2> 
   </child_node2>
   <child_node3 + attribute>
      <node3_2 + attribute>
         <node3_3>
            <node3_4 + attribute>
               TEXT COME HERE
            </node3_4> 
         </node3_3> 
      </node3_2> 
   </child_node3>
</root_node3>
```

As you see, there are lots of child nodes with different attributes. To save the time, I want to look for a special node using its attribute which I know beforehand, and I want to use its inner nodes.

For example, in the above XML file, I'm looking for `child_node2` using its attribute, and then want to save `node2_4`'s attribute` in a variable.

My problem is just to know how I go directly to the desired node (here `child_node2`) and then save the attribute of its grandchild.

I hope this explains my problem clearly.

Comment: It doesn't really - your XML isn't valid. Attributes are key-value pairs: `myatt="somevalue"`. Nor do you actually explain what you're trying to get out of the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got something like `<child_node myatt="some_value">` then the syntax for `xpath` is:

```
findnodes('//child_node[@my_att]') # find all with this attribute.
findnodes('//child_node[@my_att="some_value"]') #find this specific instance.
```

You can daisy chain the `findnodes` though, to find within the current selection criteria:

```
 foreach my $element ( $xml -> findnodes('//child_node[@my_att="some_value"]') ) {
     $element -> findnodes('//node2_4[@attribute="value"]'); #within this
 }
```

I can't be more specific unfortunately, because your sample XML isn't valid, nor do you indicate precisely which 'bit' you want to retrieve from it.

You can also compound xpath elements:

```
 //child_node[@my_att="some_value"]/somechild/someotherchild[@fish_att]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.